# How can I get the current Facebook user's public ID (not the scoped-id) or get the current user's profile photo

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know how to use the newer Facebook API/Graph to get the users public id (not the scoped id) or get access to the users public photo?  Assuming they are logged in, I just want to access the current user's public profile photo or their public URL/ID.  Any ideas?
I've looked at all the API docs and all I can find is this:

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/picture",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

But the user-id variable in this case needs to be the public user-id and all the methods that Facebook has to get the user's id returns the scoped ID, not the public ID/URL.
Any suggestions or solutions?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the global ID anymore - it would make the whole concept of the App Scoped IDs pointless.

You get the current profile picture with the following URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/[app-scoped-id]/picture` - it does work with the scoped one too.